# Is Wigner's friend paradox more paradoxical in this situation?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment, schroedingers-cat

In the Wigner's friend paradox scenario, there is an observer inside a lab, with a spin 1/2 particle inside waiting to be measured, which is generally in a superposition of spin up and spin down around the z axis. The lab is isolated, so after measurement the state of the system will be an entangled state of the particle and the inside observer, which is where the original paradox lies.

It's however usually said that this situation doesn't lead to a contradiction; it just leads to an absurd state like Schrodinger's cat scenario.

My question then is, what if instead of a spin 1/2 particle inside the lab, the inside observer performs a double-slit experiment? Will an interference pattern develop or not if the inside observer detects which slit each particle goes through? It should develop, because each particle still has amplitudes of going through each slit from the perspective of the outside observer, since the system is isolated, but the inside observer can't get an interference pattern. What's wrong?

Comment: A single quantum is not in superposition. It doesn't even exist until measured. When it exists the quantum IS simply the measured result. How would we observe an interference pattern with a single experiment, either way? An interference pattern is the result of many experiments. Paradoxes like Wigner's friend happen because people can't actually distinguish between single quanta and ensemble properties.

Answer (score 0):

Schrödinger's cat states are standard in physics and we observe them all the time.

The change that you are proposing will hide the weirdness of quantum theory. The inside observer will see that there is no interference pattern because the double slit had detectors disturbing the pattern from forming. The isolation causing the observer to be in a superposition of no-pattern states, and then you cannot see the weirdness. Only in the case that the outcomes are different would you see that there is some weirdness.

Comment: But why, if each particle has amplitudes to go through either opening, don't these amplitude interfere with each other? What's the difference between this setting and the setting in which the experiment is conducted without observing which path a particle takes at all?

Comment: The particle will not interfere because it is observed after the slit. If you change it to not observe after the slit, then in both cases there will be interference pattern, and again you will fail to observe the quantum weirdness.

Comment: The observer is never in superposition. The observer is a classical system by definition. The double slit is not even a quantum mechanical experiment. Planck's constant doesn't show up in it and we aren't measuring n-quantum correlation functions. The single quantum theory of electromagnetism at low energies is equivalent to Maxwell's equations. The only weirdness about the double-slit is the question why Feynman made such a mistake in his undergrad textbook about it and why nobody seems to notice his mistakes.

Comment: There doesnt exist a classical system. Everything in our universe is made of quantum material and exhibit quantum behaviour. Macroscopically large stuff can often be approximated by classical behaviour because of Ehrenfest theorem, but sometimes cannot be, and in those cases we have to use quantum theory to explain what they are doing. You are just wrong and if you are this level of uninterested in theoretical aspects of physics, why not just stay out of the conversation? Is it not embarrassing to claim that everybody is failing to see when Feynman made a mistake on of all things, double slit?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's important to know what Wigner Paradox is about. As you said, let's supose we have a qubit inside a lab in the state
$$
\left | \Psi \right > = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left |0 \right > + \left |1 \right > \right).
$$
And now we have a friend, inside the lab, whose purpose is to measure this qubit in computational basis, i.e., to register if measuring the state will give result $0$ or $1$ (It can be spin or anything else). Doesn't matter if the friend is a person with conciousness, or an atom. **It only matters that it can be described by quantum theory** and it register the state of the system after the measurement. So let's suppose the friend register the result in two possible states: $\left |r_0 \right >$ if the result is $0$ or $\left | r_1 \right >$ if the result is $1$. Initially, the register is in the state $\left | r_i\right>$.

Now we come to the paradox: A person inside the lab (maybe the friend herself) would describe the measurement by the measurement postulate, that leads to something like
$$
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left |0 \right > + \left |1 \right > \right)\left|r_i\right> \rightarrow \left |0 \right >\left|r_0\right>
$$
if the result is 0. Now, a person outside the lab would not describe this way. *If the system is closed*, the measurement process should be described by an interaction (by consistence of the quantum postulates). So there would be a interaction such that system+friend evolves like
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left |0 \right > + \left |1 \right > \right)\left |r_i\right> \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left |0 \right >\left| r_0\right> + \left |1 \right > \left| r_1\right> \right).
$$

This apparently is a contradiction between the measurement postulate and unitary evolution, because we arrived at two different states! However, it leads no contradiction **if we look only to te quantum system**. Tracing out the friend, we get that the state after interaction would be
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(\left|0\right>\left<0\right| +\left|1\right>\left<1\right|\right)
$$
That is a statistical misture of the two possible results of the system, which is consistent with the state inside the lab and the fact that the person outside don't know what the result of the measurement. This fact answer your question, because the interference pattern is related to the *partial state of the system*, i.e., it will disappear in both cases.

Now, the problem is that, at the time this paradox was proposed, the community was not aware about decoherence. In fact, if you replace the friend with an environment, the problem is the same, and the paradox will be

> If one can control all degrees of freedom of some environment E and describe it with a quantum state $\left| r_i \right>$, then there will be no [decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence#:%7E:text=Decoherence%20can%20be%20viewed%20as,energetic%20state%20of%20its%20surroundings.) and system+environment will be entangled, in a coherent superposition after interaction

Look that this is not a paradox, it is just a consequence of our description of the system and our ability in control and describe all degrees of freedom or not. It is not consensus if the decoherence program can solve the [measurement problem](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/14/15/201/meta?casa_token=t8q5cowBLDsAAAAA:4DkBL0mQ8_gbihX9xGYYVhGtNG6Llq3UxuT4cfmQudJ8s1kBpIDuk_O0AaXJB-8a3dVvGXblqLTs), but it's not consensus [if actually there is a measurement problem or not](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5290).

Comment: There is no measurement problem. The physicists at CERN are performing measurements on quanta all the time and they never run into any fundamental problems (not even a little). What quantum mechanics call "the measurement problem" is a misunderstanding about the nature of measurement. Measurement is an irreversible process. All of nature is irreversible. Only the non-relativistic theory emphasizes reversible systems because of the choice of the unphysical wave function rather than the physical S-matrix description. In reality all experiments are scattering experiments.